# Apex convert string mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss to standard system date (yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00)

Tags: apex, date, formatting

I am trying to convert string from google docs "1/16/2019 11:52:38" to standard system date "2019-01-16 00:00:00". I was able to achieve that using substring method but I am pretty sure there is a faster and smarter way of doing this.

I would really appreciate your help!

My method

```
private Date getFormattedDate(String timestamp) {
    String dateAsString = timestamp.substringBefore(' ');
    Integer month = Integer.valueOf(dateAsString.substringBefore('/'));
    Integer year =  Integer.valueOf(dateAsString.substringAfterLast('/'));
    Integer day = Integer.valueOf(dateAsString.substringAfter('/').substringBeforeLast('/'));
    return Date.newInstance(year, month, day);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Date.parse` method:

```
String str = '1/16/2019 11:52:38';  
Date dt = Date.parse( str.split(' ')[0] );  
system.debug(' Parsed Date is ' + dt );
```

> |DEBUG| Parsed Date is 2019-01-16 00:00:00

Refer [Date Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_date.htm)

If you want to change from mm/dd/yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy format, use below approach.

```
Date dToday = Date.today(); //DEBUG|>>>>2019-01-17 00:00:00
String dateStr = Date.today().format();
DateTime dt = DateTime.newInstance(dToday.year(), dToday.month(),dToday.day());
dateStr = dt.format('dd/MM/yyyy');
System.debug('>>>>' + dateStr); //>>>>17/01/2019
```

Comment: This is what I have already tested, it throws an error "Invalid date: 1/15/2019" :(

Comment: It works fine for me and given result as `2019-01-15 00:00:00`

Comment: May be it won't support in your locale. What is your locale?

Comment: That seems to be right, is it possible to just change mm/dd/yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy in apex?

Comment: Yes @Tomek . First convert date to datetime and you can use `Datetime.format('dd/MM/yyyy')`

Comment: @Tomek See my updated answer for changing mm/dd/yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: That would work if I could parse this as a DateTime but it will still throw an error about Invalid date/time

Comment: @Tomek do you have sample datetime input to convert to dd/mm/yyyy format?